# How did I damage my Android Keystores?

Tags: java, android, keystore

Aside from losing a password, what causes the keystore to be corrupted/ tampered with, rendering it unusable?

My keystore files reside in a dedicated folder marked as read-only.  After having already lost access to a keystore, I am 100% certain my passwords are correct, as I have made over a dozen updates to published apps in the past few months, and the keystore files have not been opened.  I made sure they are valid until at least 2050.  I know the issue is unrecoverable, but its happened more than once now.  So what is causing it?

Comment: Explains the output. Does `keytool -list -keystore <file>` returns something or is just the file corrupted?

Comment: I would recommend keeping a backup of the keystore somewhere off your computer. Then even if the file is corrupted you can retrieve it.

Comment: If they are truly "read only" and have not had that permission removed/readded (although software, including terrible anti-malware or [working] malware, can do this itself) then the only way that the data could have been changed is by filesystem/hardware corruption .. however, it is *unlikely* (from a fs/hardware view) that *only* said files were targeted, and affected multiple times. (Given only this information my vote is for malware or a broken agent .. a full system scan/clean/reset, including that of the hardware, is in order.)

Comment: @shkschneider - while using keytool, after entering the location it asks for the keystore password, yet entering the correct password gives the java.io.IOException for the tampered/wrong password.

Comment: @user2864740 - Agreed, it seems unlikely, however since I am using two separate keystores for two separate apps, only one has gone corrupted twice, the other unaffected so maybe it is targeted some how.